# Checkin if pressed inside rectF in onTouchEvent

Tags: android, canvas, touch-event

I've been working on a very simple little application using an extended view. 
The problem is that i can't find what been pressed in my onTouchEvent. 
I've understood that i've to compare the pressure-points (x and y) to the elements and see which one it could be.

But...
I've declared a rectangle using:

```
Paint color= new Paint();
color.setColor(Color.BLACK);
rectF = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f) ;
canvas.drawRect(rectF, color);
```

So far so good, but in the onTouchEvent function

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction() ;
    float x = event.getX() ;
    float y = event.getY() ;

    switch(action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        if(rectF().contains(x, y)) {
            // Something should happen
        }

    }

    invalidate();
    return true ;
}
```

I set the rectF with some kind of relative points ranging from 0-1, but the X and Y i get from the event ranges from 0 and upwards depending on screen-size.

Can I easily convert either of the values?

**Edit**

Thought someone was interested in the final solution...

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction() ;
    float x = event.getX() ;
    float y = event.getY() ;

    int width = this.getWidth() ;
    int height = this.getHeight() ;

    switch(action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        if(rectF().contains(x/width, y/height)) {
            // Something should happen
        }

    }

    return true ;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of the touch point and the RectF have to be on the same reference scale in oreder to be compared properly. Meaning that if you declare your `RectF` to use relative sizes (0-1) you will either need to :

1: normalize the `MotionEvent` position by your screen size

OR 2: "denormalize" the `RectF` dimensions by your actual screen size.

I think 1 is generally preferrable as it lets you define your rects in terms of relative layout, independent of the actual screen size and convert the event positions on-the-fly.

like this : `rectF.contains(x/screenWidth, y/screenHeight);`

You can retrieve the screen dimensions by calling 
`Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()` in your Activity and then calling `display.getWidth()` or `display.getHeight()`

Comment: I found that i rather wanted the width and height of the view, so I used `this.getHeight()` and `this.getWidth()` instead.

Comment: @dubbe sure, I wasnt aware of your context, so I gave advice on the simplest case

Comment: I know, and it was perfect advice, i just clarified it in case someone else is searching for the same thing!